# Open the Attachment Details popup

Tags: attachments, media-library

I'm trying to open the Attachment Details popup, but with this code it shows all the images

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( '.attachments' ).on( 'click', '.attachment', function( event ) {
                var $el = $( this );
                var selected = $( this ).attr( 'data-id' );

                //alert(selected);
                event.preventDefault();

                console.log(wp.media);
                // Create the media frame.
                gallery_items_frame = wp.media.frames.gallery_items = wp.media({
                    title: $el.data( 'choose' ),
                    button: {
                        text: $el.data( 'update' )
                    },
                    states: [
                        new wp.media.controller.Library({
                            title: $el.data( 'choose' ),
                            multiple: false,
                            selection: 'single',
                            contentUserSetting: true
                        })
                    ]
                });

                // Select the attachment when the frame opens
                gallery_items_frame.on( 'open', function() {
                    var selection = gallery_items_frame.state().get( 'selection' );
                    selection.reset( selected ? [ wp.media.attachment( selected ) ] : [] ); 
                });

                // Open the modal.
                gallery_items_frame.open();
            });
        });
```

This opens the "Media Library" successfully, but what I'm looking for is the "Attachment Details" where it shows just one image and the details